# Trigger GIT build in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) via API for specific commit

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm looking at building some integration between Github and Team Services builds so that I can get a Team Services build running when a Github pull request is created or updated; this isn't supported directly right now that I can tell.

However, looking at the documentation for the [REST API for Team Services build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds), it says I need to pass in the name of the branch to build in the body.

Pull requests don't have a branch. I do have a commit ID though. Can I pass the SHA-1 for the commit as the branch name? Or is there some other way to tell it to go to a specific commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the pull request as the source branch via this format:

```
refs/pull/pullrequestid/head
```

[image]